# passing cursor variable into a query

Tags: sql-server, oracle, t-sql, cursor

I am an Oracle developer trying to learn T-SQL.
I have a table with one column in it (`table_name`). I need to be able to loop over all rows and find all columns for a given table. Then I need to output the result of it to the file.
In Oracle it is pretty simple by using cursor in this fashion:

```
cursor my_curr is select table_name from my_table;
for x in my_curr loop
   select column_name from user_tab_columns
   where table_name = x.table_name;

   utl_file ..... (writing result to an OS file)
end loop;
```

What is the equivalent of the above in T-SQL? How would I use cursor variable to pass it into the query?

Thanks,
Eugene

Comment: You can use cursor but you can not write to external file using t-sql.

Answer (score 1):

Declare a variable for a column result, and the cursor.

```
declare @name varchar(100)
declare my_curr cursor 
for select table_name from my_table;
```

Open the cursor

```
open my_curr
```

Fetch the first row into the variable

```
fetch from my_curr into @name
```

`@@Fetch_Status` is whether the fetch was a success

```
while @@Fetch_Status=0
begin
```

Using the variable fetched from the cursor, compare with the system tables to get the columns. Newer versions of SQL server can also use Information_Schema, but this will work on all versions

```
    select c.name from syscolumns c
         inner join sysobjects o on c.id = o.id
    where o.name = @name;  

   --utl_file ..... (writing result to an OS file)
```

Fetch the next row

```
   fetch next from my_curr into @name

end
```

Dispose of the cursor

```
close my_curr
deallocate my_curr
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. My ultimate goal is to display differences between 2 tables. So, I'd have to fetch table_name into @name and then run the query to pull the list of columns to be used in the following: 'select *  from
  (select <list of columns> from table1
   except
   select <list of columns> from table2) x
union all
select 'table2' as tblName, *  from
  (select <list of columns> from table2
   except select <list of columns> from table1) x' Is it possible?

Comment: The differences in their structure? You could join the results of this query against results for a query of the existing table to find the differences.  Or you could use a tool such as SQL Server data tools... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/tools.aspx

Comment: The difference in data. I have 500+ tables to go through.

Comment: I'd look for a tool...! eg:redgate SQL data compare